# What is the distribution of the modulo of a uniformly-distributed random variable

Tags: uniform-distribution

This feels like something that's easy to answer, but maybe not. (For the record, this isn't homework from school, it's to settle an argument I'm having with a colleague.)

I have a random variable $X$ that's a value in $K = [0, 2^{64})$. Given that $X$ is uniformly distributed over $K$ (that is, the probability density function of $X$ is $f(x) = \frac{1}{2^{64}}$), what is the distribution of $Y = X \bmod k$?

My gut says it's uniformly distributed over $M = [0, k)$ (i.e., the pdf of $Y$ is $f(y)=\frac{1}{k}$) but I can't quite sort the math to get me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gut is right in the limit of $n \to \infty$ in $K = [0,2^n)$ but slightly wrong for finite $n$ (which is $64$ as posed in the question).  (Which is why you are having trouble proving the uniform distribution -- it is not quite true.)

The point is that up and not including to $\left \lfloor \frac{2^{64}}k \right\rfloor$ there are an equal number of instances of each value of $Y$.  But in the interval
$\left \lfloor \frac{2^{64}}k \right\rfloor \leq k < 2^{64}$ there is one instance of each number $n : 0 \leq n < 2^{64} - \left \lfloor \frac{2^{64}}k \right\rfloor$ and no instances equal to or greater than $ 2^{64} - \left \lfloor \frac{2^{64}}k \right\rfloor$.

So the distribution looks almost uniform; it is flat up to $2^{64} -\left \lfloor \frac{2^{64}}k \right\rfloor$ then takes a tiny step downward and remains flat thereafter.  But that is not a uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is the difference between math and engineering - to an engineer, this is _close enough_ to uniform for our purposes.

Comment: (I say that because $k \ll 2^{64}$, nominally 1000.)

Comment: Is it better to say this is a bimodal distribution where $$f(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{@{}lr@{}}
        \left\lceil\frac{2^{64}}{k}\right\rceil, & 0\le y \lt (2^{64}\bmod {k),}\\
        \left\lfloor\frac{2^{64}}{k}\right\rfloor,  & (2^{64}\bmod k) \le y \lt k
        \end{array}\right\}
 $$

I'm questioning the word _bimodal_ but I think the above function accurately describes the pdf.

Comment: Isn't it some confusion here about *k* which is both the same for a value of *K* and the modulos. If I understand correctly it could be better to write it Y = X mod q because surely the k in mod k is not the same as the value taken K=k...?

Answer (score 1):

It is not uniform unless $k$ is power of $2$. For example, if you replace $64$ with $2$ and take $k = 3$, you get $P(Y \in [0, 1)) = \frac{1}{2}$, but $P(Y \in [1, 2)) = P(Y = [2, 3)) = \frac{1}{4}$.

If $k$ is power of $2$ let $n = \frac{2^{64}}{k}$. We have $P(Y \in [0, x)) = P(X \in [0, x)) + P(X \in [k, k + x)) + \ldots + P(X \in [(n - 1)k, (n - 1)k + x))$.

Each term is equal to $\frac{x}{2^{64}}$, and there are total of $n$ of them, so sum is $\frac{x}{k}$.

Comment: Good point on the $k = 2 ^ m$.